# Mysql / Python : "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" when looping

Tags: python, mysql

I've a loop like this

```
cursor = db.cursor()

while True:
    qry = "SELECT id FROM data WHERE parsed = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(qry)
    result_qry = cursor.fetchone()
    id = result_qry[0]

    # Some stuff

    qry2 = "UPDATE data SET parsed = 1 WHERE id = id"
    cursor.execute(qry2)
    db.commit()
```

It works for the first loop.

But in the second loop, I've

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeanbenoit/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/htdocs/carter_python/parsing.py", line 41, in <module>
    id = result_qry[0]
         ~~~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The SELECT query answers None. But if I play the same query in PHPmyadmin, I've some results.

If I comment the UPDATE query at the end, I don't have this issue.

I try to fix it for hours, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253727/discussion-on-question-by-cyberrookie-mysql-python-typeerror-nonetype-ob); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The second query is not just updating all the row that you fetched with the first query, it's updating all rows because `id = id` is always true. You need to substitute the `id` variable into the query.

```
    qry2 = "UPDATE data SET parsed = 1 WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(qry2, (id,))
```

Also, you need to break out of the loop when the first query doesn't find any rows with `parsed = 0`.

```
    result_qry = cursor.fetchone()
    if not result_qry:
        break

    id = result_qry[0]
```